# Objective-c add a stroke to an arc

Tags: objective-c, drawrect

I'm following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on creating an arc and though I don't get any errors I also don't get an arc drawn on the screen. Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Here's my code:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef) createArcPathFromBottomOfRect : (CGRect) rect : (CGFloat) arcHeight {

    CGRect arcRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arcHeight, rect.size.width, arcHeight);

    CGFloat arcRadius = (arcRect.size.height/2) + (pow(arcRect.size.width, 2) / (8*arcRect.size.height));
    CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x + arcRect.size.width/2, arcRect.origin.y + arcRadius);

    CGFloat angle = acos(arcRect.size.width / (2*arcRadius));
    CGFloat startAngle = radians(180) + angle;
    CGFloat endAngle = radians(360) - angle;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcRadius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    return path;

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGMutablePathRef myArcPath = [self createArcPathFromBottomOfRect:self.frame:10.0];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 1);
    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(currentContext, red);
    /*CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, 0, rect.size.height - 7);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 7);*/
    CGContextAddPath(currentContext, myArcPath);
    CGContextClip(currentContext);
    CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);


}
```

Comment: I tried the code and it doesn't even draw anything.

Comment: I know, that's why I posted the question. : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two errors: In

```
CGMutablePathRef myArcPath = [self createArcPathFromBottomOfRect:self.frame:10.0];
```

you probably should replace `self.frame` by `self.bounds`, because the former relates
to the coordinates in the superview.

And you probably should remove

```
CGContextClip(currentContext);
```

I don't know why you have that, but it modifies the current clip path and then set the current path to
an empty path, so that the following `CGContextStrokePath()` paints nothing.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked, to some extent. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for though. I'm trying to just get the arc but what I got was a polygon with 3 straight sides and an arc on the bottom - how would I delete the left, right and top lines?

Comment: @PruitIgoe: Remove the three `CGPathAddLineToPoint()` calls so that only an ARC is drawn with `CGPathAddArc()`. - (If that does not yet give the desired result then perhaps add a sketch to your question showing what you exactly need.)

Comment: Perfect (and makes sense), just need to move a view along that line and I'm done. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @PruitIgoe: You are welcome. You might consider to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark, thanks.

Comment: Dang, sorry, thought I did.